# Is there a Postgres array overlap (&&) operator for EF Core 3.0 Npgsql

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Given a `DBSet<Tasks>` with a column `tags text[]`. Is there a way in EF Core Npgsql to query for tags in common with a supplied list of tags using the Postgres overlap (&&) operator e.g.

```
select * from tasks where tag && '{bug, feature}'
```

I can't find anything related to this, and I'd like to avoid client-side evaluation. I'd like to do something like

```
var tags = new List<string> { "bug", "feature" };
var foo = _db.Tasks.Where(x => x.Tags && tags); // obviously this doesn't work
```

I also tried the linq contains method

```
var foo = _db.Tasks.Where(x => x.Tags.Any(x => tags.Contains(x)));
```

but received the exception that the linq expression could not be translated.

Comment: Did ypu tried use an array and Contains method?

Comment: Yep, tried the contains with no joy as the expression couldn't be translated. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Did you tried something like this?: var foo = _db.Tasks.Where(item => tags.Contains(item.Tags))

Comment: Yes none of these linq expressions can be translated. It seems the Npqsql EF Core driver has very limited array operator support but I'm looking for info on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for array overlap (&&) and containment (@>) has been added for version 3.1, which should be released very soon (see https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1135).

If any other operators are needed and not translated, please open a new issue.